# Magento 1.9 local.xml security warning

Tags: htaccess, apache

I'm trying to setup `Magento 1.9.0.1` under `Apache 2.4.9` without the `access_compat` module. As of Apache 2.4 the old access control directives are deprecated [[1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)] and should no longer be used. I'm now trying to convert magento's `.htaccess` to be compatible with both versions:

```
# apache 2.2
<IfModule !access_compat_module>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# apache 2.4
<IfModule access_compat_module>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

This seems to work for external connections (browser, wget, ...) but does not work for `Zend_Http_Client` connections. Magento checks access to `app/etc/local.xml` in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Security.php` and `read()` succeeds with `200 OK` returning the contents of said file.

Also, Apache does not log access to said file in its access log for some reason when accessed via Zend_Http_Client. `wget` access gets logged.

What did I miss? Any magic going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no logging" of the request makes me think the request isn't even happening.  i.e. You configuration is fine, but what you think is making a request to your server is actually making a request to another server.

You mentioned `Zend_Http_Client` — however, this object isn't used in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Security.php`.  I'm assuming you meant this chunk of code.

```
private function _isFileAccessible()
{
    $defaultUnsecureBaseURL = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL);

    $http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
    $http->setConfig(array('timeout' => $this->_verificationTimeOut));
    $http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $defaultUnsecureBaseURL . $this->_filePath);
    $responseBody = $http->read();
    $responseCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($responseBody);
    $http->close();

    return $responseCode == 200;
}
```

Here Magento's using a `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` object to make the request (which is just a wrapper for `curl` functions).  Try adding some debugging code to view the URL its requesting.

```
$defaultUnsecureBaseURL = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL);
var_dump($defaultUnsecureBaseURL);
Mage::Log($defaultUnsecureBaseURL);
```

My guess is you'll find it's using a different URL than the one you used in the browser and `wget` requests.

Comment: Good catch. It actually fetched the config from a different deployment.

Comment: @keks Pretty easy catch after you've done the same thing 8,351 times yourself :)